# Hosting PHP and Node.js apps on the same server with multiple domains

Tags: node.js, dns, lighttpd, iptables, vhosts

I have a Linode VPS, currently running lighttpd to serve up my PHP websites and listening on port 80.

I'm also running Node.js, which listens on port 81, and uses websockets and HTTP to interact with the client.

There's a couple of different domains that I would like to point to this server. Ideally, I would like the domains which host the PHP sites to all talk to the same lighttpd server, and the sites which use node.js would somehow redirect to the port node.js is listening on unbeknownst to the client (e.g. no 30x redirect).

```
example-php1.com:80 -> linodebox:80 lighttpd /var/www/example1
example-php2.com:80 -> linodebox:80 lighttpd /var/www/example2
example-node.com:80 -> linodebox:81 node.js
```

Is there a way to do this, either by setting DNS entries or tweaking iptables? Does lighttpd need to be a proxy for node.js? The websockets feature needs to work without any fallbacks, and visiting a non node domain, e.g. `example-php1.com:81`, should not expose the node application.

I feel the perfect solution wouldn't require changes to existing application code nor require proxying between software web servers, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

What's up Tom!?

I recommend HA-Proxy, it's one of the most high performance proxies out there and should accomplish what you're trying to do there.

I'm doing something similar with nginx acting as a proxy, it's easy but not the fastest.

HA-Proxy's website is here http://haproxy.1wt.eu

If you wanted a 'pure' solution, you could probably get the answer from looking at ha-proxy's source code. You can't really do it with iptables. Something has to read the HTTP header to determine where the request came from to route it locally.

Answer (score 0):

I had basically the same problem and I ended up using [node-http-proxy](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy) (also available in npm as `http-proxy`).

You just need a simple config file:

```
{
  router: {
    'example-php1.com': 'linodebox:80',
    'example-php2.com': 'linodebox:80',
    'example-node.com': 'linodebox:81
  }
}
```

Then just run `node-http-proxy --config options.json` and you're set. If you want to run lighttpd and node on the same machine, you'll have to start lighttpd on a different port (I use 81 for php and 3000 for node - adjusting the config is easy). I also use [forever](https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever) to manage my node instances.

Answer (score 0):

Ya'll are gonna hate me...

I ended up going with a second IP address, then followed the [Linode tutorial](http://library.linode.com/networking/configuring-static-ip-interfaces) to setup multiple static IPs. Then, I configured lighttpd to bind to one IP address and Node.js to bind to another IP address.

This isn't a great solution as it doesn't scale.

Answer (score 0):

Update: lighttpd 1.4.46 (released back in 2017) added multiple ways to accept WebSocket connections:

- [lighttpd mod_wstunnel](https://wiki.lighttpd.net/Docs_ModWSTunnel)
- [lighttpd mod_proxy](https://wiki.lighttpd.net/Docs_ModProxy)
- [lighttpd mod_cgi](https://wiki.lighttpd.net/Docs_ModCGI)